# Is it possible to disable comments for videos in WordPress when using BuddyPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed buddypress in my WordPress project to have a newsfeed. Is it possible to disable comments if me or the other users posted a video?

I had tried the "bp_activity_can_comment" which will return false and put it on functions.php. I also tried adding some condition to check if the media is a photo or video.

```
if ( 'video' === $media->media_type ) {
     add_filter('bp_activity_can_comment', $return_false); 
 }
```

I expect that if the user post a video, commenting would be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the comments for particular post from admin panel as well [see Link](https://en.support.wordpress.com/enable-and-disable-comments-for-published-posts-and-pages/)